# Create SparseTensor from dequeued batch of values, indices, shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to feed tensors, some of which are sparse, to a model from RAM.  I have created a PaddingFIFOQueue into which I am queuing the indices, values, and shapes for my sparse tensors separately under the assumption that sparse values cannot be batched from RAM by some other method (If that's not the case please let me know).  They need to be padded as the sequences are all of different lengths.

I am dequeuing the following...

```
indices = [batch size, None, 2]
values = [batch size, None]
shapes = [batch size, 2]
```

I have attempted to use these values to create a SparseTensor but am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: Shape (512, ?, 2) must have rank 2
```

The main portion of the code is as follows...

```
indices, values, shapes = self.queue.dequeue_many(batch_size)
sp_tensor = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, shapes)
```

I assume this is because SparseTensor is expecting a rank 2 tensor and not a batch of rank 2 tensors (as indicated by the error message) but I am not sure how to convert the batch.

Comment: Have you considered [sparse_merge](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/sparse_ops/conversion#sparse_merge)?

Comment: The tensors that I am dequeueing are dense tensors.  `sparse_merge` seems to what a sparse tensor for its inputs.  `sp_ids: A SparseTensor with values property of type int32 or int64.
sp_values: ASparseTensor of any type.`

Comment: Right, silly of me. I've put something together in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with a bit of tiling and reshaping:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def sparse_tensor_merge(indices, values, shape):
  """Creates a SparseTensor from batched indices, values, and shapes.

  Args:
    indices: A [batch_size, N, D] integer Tensor.
    values: A [batch_size, N] Tensor of any dtype.
    shape: A [batch_size, D] Integer Tensor.
  Returns:
    A SparseTensor of dimension D + 1 with batch_size as its first dimension.
  """
  merged_shape = tf.reduce_max(shape, axis=0)
  batch_size, elements, shape_dim = tf.unstack(tf.shape(indices))
  index_range_tiled = tf.tile(tf.range(batch_size)[..., None],
                              tf.stack([1, elements]))[..., None]
  merged_indices = tf.reshape(
      tf.concat([tf.cast(index_range_tiled, tf.int64), indices], axis=2),
      [-1, 1 + tf.size(merged_shape)])
  merged_values = tf.reshape(values, [-1])
  return tf.SparseTensor(
      merged_indices, merged_values,
      tf.concat([[tf.cast(batch_size, tf.int64)], merged_shape], axis=0))
```

So for example:

```
batch_indices = tf.constant(
    [[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
     [[0, 0], [1, 1]]], dtype=tf.int64)
batch_values = tf.constant(
    [[0.1, 0.2],
     [0.3, 0.4]])
batch_shapes = tf.constant(
    [[2, 2],
     [3, 2]], dtype=tf.int64)

merged = sparse_tensor_merge(batch_indices, batch_values, batch_shapes)

with tf.Session():
  print(merged.eval())
```

Prints:

```
SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]]), 
  values=array([ 0.1       ,  0.2       ,  0.30000001,  0.40000001],
      dtype=float32), 
  dense_shape=array([2, 3, 2]))
```

Notice that the shape of the combined SparseTensor is the original batch dimension followed by the max across the batch for each of the other dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive explanation and snippet.  This worked great.